# How to change TimeStamp Time Zone in Php or PhpMyAdmin

Tags: timezone, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

When i submitting form My Timestamp function takes Hostgator Server time.   But i need to change my time zone "(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi". How i can change my time zone through PHP, PhpMyAdmin, or Hostgator server. if there any possible option plz help.

Answer (score 1):

In Your header file or some common file which included in all the pages there you add this line in the top.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```